# Words for the tendency of a system to either accelerate or reduce changes

Tags: single-word-requests

Dynamic systems often have feedback mechanisms whereby changes in the system can either be self-reinforcing, causing the system to change more once it has started changing, or self-opposing, causing the system to reduce or reverse changes.

There are two words for systems with these two properties, the two words effectively being antonyms, and I have forgotten them for lack of usage. What are they?

Comment: You mean "positive feedback" and "negative feedback"?  Positive feedback is reenforcing and can cause the system to go off the deep end (think of audio feedback in an audio system).  Negative feedback is stabilizing and helps things stay on an even keel.

Comment: Perhaps you are thinking of an ***amplifier*** and a ***dampener*** (or ***canceler***).

Comment: Yes, but I think there are specific words for them. If I dug through a book on chaos theory I'd probably find them quickly, but I don't have any such book handy. It's not an amplifier or a dampener, I think those are specific to signals.

Comment: You mean *divergent* and *convergent*?

Comment: Well, back in, I think, 1970, when I had my control theory class, it was "positive feedback" and "negative feedback".

Comment: I'm finding plenty of signal *damping* circuits, but not so many for signal *dampening*.

Answer (score 2):

[stability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability_criterion)

*[stable](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stability), [unstable/instability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Instability)*

> In control theory, and especially stability theory, a stability
>   criterion establishes when a system is stable. A number of stability
>   criteria are in common use:
>
> - Bistritz stability criterion
> - Circle criterion
> - Jury stability criterion
> - Liénard–Chipart criterion
> - Nyquist stability criterion
> - Routh–Hurwitz stability criterion
> - Vakhitov–Kolokolov stability criterion
> - Barkhausen stability criterion

Another related pair of words with precise meaning in control theory are:

*controllable, uncontrollable*

See [this lecture](http://www.mathematik.uni-stuttgart.de/studium/infomat/mst/linearekontrolltheorie/folien/lec3.pdf) for the mathematical details.

Comment: +1, but I'm specifically looking for the pair of words.

Comment: @jprete a pair other than stable/unstable?

Answer (score 1):

If the system is electronic, the antonyms would be a signal *amplifier* or signal *damping* circuit.

This [page has a schematic](http://www.next.gr/light-laser-led/light-sensing/Photodiode-signal-conditioner-l12135.html) and says:

> The 0.033 (microfarad) value at A3's compensation pins gives good loop **damping** if the circuit is built using the array's transistors in the location shown.

Its inverse, an amplifier, is well known.

If you are looking only about system changes, then a **feedback loop** may provide [positive feedback](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Positive_feedback) (think a microphone screech, magnifying a change) or negative feedback, limiting the changes.

Comment: Neither "damping" nor "amplification" necessarily involves feedback.

Answer (score -1):

Regenerative tends to repair itself, and degenerative tends to continue toward deeper dysfunction?